# WPF: creation of editor for further work with content of different DB tables leads to code duplication. How to avoid it?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, nhibernate, data-binding

I'm rather new to C#/WPF (most time I worked with Java) and continue learning data binding.

I have a DB (I use SQLite and NHibernate) with two tables which have same structure (name and value columns) but different content. To create, update, delete, get data I use generic class `NHibernateRepository` which implements interface for mentioned functionality. Here they are:

```
public class NHibernateCommandRepository<T> : ICommandRepository<T>
    where T : class 
{
    public T Get(Guid id)
    {
        //implementation of data selection by ID
    }

    //implementation of other methods
}

public interface ICommandRepository<T> 
    where T : class 
{
    T Get(Guid id);
    void Save(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    List<T> GetAll();
}
```

I need to implement editor window where I can add, remove, edit existing entity from these tables. So I created two alike editors - one editor for the first table, another for the second table.

Here is **XAML** part:

```
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0">
        <Button Name="AddBtn" Click="AddBtn_Click" Content="Add"/>
        <Button Name="EditBtn" Click="EditBtn_Click" Content="Edit"/>
        <Button Name="RemoveBtn" Click="RemoveBtn_Click" Content="Remove"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ListBox Name="EntitiesList" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
</DockPanel>
```

And this is how **code-behind** part looks like:

```
public partial class CommonCommandEditor : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<CommandEntity> entities = new ObservableCollection<CommandEntity>(); //CommandEntity implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface
    private ICommandRepository<CommonCommand> _commandRepo;

    //the second class differs here
    //private ICommandRepository<QuizCommand> _commandRepo;

    public CommonCommandEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _commandRepo = new NHibernateCommandRepository<CommonCommand>();
        //the second class differs here
        //_commandRepo = new NHibernateCommandRepository<QuizCommand>();

        InitEntitiesList();
        CommandsList.ItemsSource = entities;
    }

    private void AddBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //opens entity editor window
    }

    private void EditBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //opens entity editor window
    }

    private void RemoveBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (EntitiesList.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            var entity = EntitiesList.SelectedItem as CommandEntity;
            entities.Remove(entity);
            _commandRepo.Delete(_commandRepo.Get(entity.ID));
        }
    }

    //This method is duplicated in both classes
    private void InitEntitiesList()
    {
        entities.Clear();
        foreach (var command in _commandRepo.GetAll())
        {
            entities.Add(new CommandEntity(command.Id, command.Name, command.Value));
        }
    }
}
```

I have a lot of duplication in code like the same editor window (XAML part), method which populates `ObservableCollection` with data from DB, button clicks open the same entity editor (a window with two fields name and value, which are initialized with strings) and so on.

I tried to make editor's class generic, it would have to remove almost all duplication. But this will work in Java, and in C# I receive compilation error (one of them:

> `The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context`).

Is it possible to achieve clean code in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

The error with InitializeComponent says that the function isn't defined. In your project, the partial class CommonCommandEditor somehow can't find its related .xaml file anymore.

Anyway you can solve this error by backing up your code,then right click on your project, choose Add--> User Control --> Add a new WPF user control "CommonCommandEditor" again. Then move .xaml code and .cs code to new created control and it'll works.

For databinding I suggest you to use MVVM Framework, for example [Caliburn.Micro](http://hintdesk.com/c-wpf-mvvm-databinding-2014/). It does support you to enhance your databinding.